# one .env file not being called but others are in javascript with Twilio

Tags: javascript, twilio

the values of my account SID and Auth tokens are working but when I try to use the value of a enviroment variable to use as the body of my message it won't work.

where am I going wrong here?

```
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
const msg = process.env.MY_MESSAGE;

client.messages
  .create({
     body: msg,
     from: '+17777777777',
     to: '+13333333333'
   })
  .then(message => console.log(message.dateCreated));
```

Comment: Did you check your environmental variables? What OS are you using? For OS-X, type env in terminal and check for `MY_MESSAGE`.

Comment: I'm using WIN-10 where should I check in command prompt? I get this `C:\Users\Yanky>.env
'.env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I think it is `set` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1

Comment: I was able to set it, thanks! but would you know why it didn't work through system properties if previous ones worked. and I cant't even see the one I just set there

Comment: Not sure. Maybe you needed to close an already open CMD session and re-open it to source the new environment.